# Memory Management List<byte[]> vs List<Bitmap>

Tags: c#, memory, bitmap, byte

I have an List of Bitmaps defined as such:

```
List<Bitmap> bmpList = new List<Bitmap>();

void CameraWindow_NewFrame(ref Bitmap newFrame)
{
  bmpList.Add((Bitmap)newFrame.Clone());
}
```

I populate this list with 20-50 thousands bitmaps once or twice a minute or so.  The problem is that I don't have time to cycle through each bitmap in the list and Dispose of it.  I only have time to clear the list.  Will GC clean this up? Is there any advantage to converting the Bitmaps to byte[] and storing them in a List?  Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: You don't have time to dispose?  How long is disposing taking?  Anyhow, yes do the byte array, as you don't need to dispose there.  I'd be curious to see how your adding the bitmaps into your list.

Comment: If you can't dispose them, you should reuse the bitmaps

Comment: Hey Trey.  Yea, it's takes a good 5 seconds or so to loop through that list and dispose each one.   I'm adding them from a camera.  I'll add the code above.

Comment: It is not possible to store that many bitmaps.  Look in the Output window, good odds that you'll see it filled with exception notifications.  Bitmap.Clone() is almost never not good enough for the typical camera firmware, you have to make a deep copy with the Bitmap(Image) constructor.  Now you have a lot less time, a camera is a serious firehose of data and you'll have to settle for what is practical.  This isn't.

Comment: Yea it is, i'm doing it and it works.  Perhaps you're on a 32 bit system and are running into memory walls.

Answer (score 0):

GC will clean them up ... eventually. However, leaving thousands of bitmaps undisposed might quickly deplete your available memory, making your application to stumble and become unresponsive at times - something you would probably like to avoid.

If you do not have time to properly dispose those bitmaps in your working thread, you might launch a separate thread to dispose those bitmaps you do not need any more. So instead of

```
bmpList.Clear();
```

you do something like

```
LaunchThreadToDisposeBitmaps(bmpList);
bmpList = new List<Bitmap>();
```

where LaunchThreadToDisposeBitmaps launches a new thread which iterates over the list disposes every bitmap and finishes
.

Comment: Eventually is key, I have done a similar application to what your describing and memory was a huge mess if you did not dispose.

Comment: I absolutely agree. Updated the answer to make my suggestion more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback rs.  I've thought of that, the only probelm is that my list me need to be used before the thread is done clearing.  Se, then i'm looking at having multiple list.  Best I can so far clearing a list a bitmaps without disposing is bad but clearing a list of byte[] is no big deal.  I'm gonna convert them unless somebody tells me why that's a bad idea.

Comment: I replaced bmpList.Clear() with bmpList=new List<Bitmap>() exactly to give you a shiny new list immediately ready to be used while the old one gets slowly disposed in a background. Converting to byte[] is not good just because it causes much additional overhead (something you're trying to escape) and might be even slower and more time-consuming then just plain dispose the list elements one-by-one in the main thread.

Comment: oh, does it work that way?  I honestly didn't know that.

Comment: Yeah, also keep in mind the threading of the dispose will be an issue if your using the SAME list... you want to have an array of lists you rotate through or some such.. IE fill list1, spawn thread to dispose, fill list2, thread to dispose, etc.

Comment: yea, gotta have an array of list because they are passed by reference.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the list?

If you make a list with new object a minute or 2 later, you cloud clear the list instead.

If the first object added is also the first removed use a linkedlist and a coroutine or on update check if you should remove it.